# add new image object via url jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am try to create a new image object in jquery. I have the image src and i want the image object to be created dynamically. I know that i can have a new image in this way:

```
$image = new Image();
```

but what i want to do is a replace so i don't need a new image from scratch. The above code shows in my console something like this:

```
<img src="url_of_image">
```

How can i create an image by using the src url instead of making new object?
I tried the syntaxes below but doesn't work:

```
var img = '<img src='+new_url+'';
var img = $('<img src='+new_url+'');
```

any idea???

I added:

```
    var new_url = url;
    var img = new RImage(new_url);
    console.log(img);
    img.onload = function() {
    var img_w_original=this.width;
    var img_h_original=this.height;
    img_w=img_w_original;img_h=img_h_original;
    img_ratio=img_w/img_h;
}
if (banner_ratio>=1)
        {
        if (banner_ratio<=img_ratio)
            {
            img_w=banner.width;
            img_h=Math.round(img_w/img_ratio);
            }else{
            img_h=banner.height;
            img_w=Math.round(img_h*img_ratio);
            }
        }else{
        if (banner_ratio<=img_ratio)
            {
            img_w=banner.width;
            img_h=Math.round(img_w/img_ratio);
            }else{
            img_h=banner.height;
            img_w=Math.round(img_h*img_ratio);
            }
        }
```

i cant get img_w and img_h.. why??

Answer (score 0):

The last one is almost there

```
var img = $('<img />', {src : new_url});
```

now all you have to do is insert it into the DOM somewhere !

Answer (score 0):

```
function Image(path, width, height, target) {
    $('<img src="'+ path +'">').load(function() {
        $(this).width(width).height(height).appendTo(target);
    });
}
```